# Sorting values within a pandas dataframe group by

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with three columns: account_number, balance_date, and amount.

I need to calculate, for each account, the amount moving average, where the amounts within each account are sorted by balance_date. This is what I do:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['account_number', 'balance_date'])
df['amount_mov_average'] = df.groupby('account_number')['amount'].rolling(3).mean().droplevel(0)
```

I have problems with the calculation and I'm not sure it's because I don't have sorted by balance_date within each account.

Question is: do I need to sort again by balance_date after the group by, or the `sort_values` that I do before the group by is enough?

Am I forced to create an index with account_number and balance_date? I prefer not to add complexity creating a new index.

Comment: Can you help to add a sample dataframe and the output you're expecting which you're not getting using your method

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: the index needs to be reset after the `sort_values` as the rolling works with the index, regardless of how the data is sorted